# web3 encodeFunctionCall does not work (well 2 specific functions calls together in 1 transaction does not work)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am trying to execute `deposit` and `withdraw` function from `yDAI (yearn.finance)` within the same transaction using web3 encodeFunctionCall. `deposit` function works, but, `withdraw` function fails. However, if I execute the `withdraw` function alone separately, then it works.

```
let abi1 = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall( { "name": "deposit", "type": "function", "inputs": [ { "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" } ] }, [web3.utils.toWei((1000).toString(), 'Ether')] );

let abi2 = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall( {"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"withdrawAll","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}, [] );
```

I am encoding the above in a js file and then calling a function present in my smart contract using an array. Code present in smart contract:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < _addrs.length; i++)
    address(_addrs[i]).call(_bytecode[i]);
```

There are no error messages.

Here is the code and abi for `yDAI (yearn.finance)`.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xACd43E627e64355f1861cEC6d3a6688B31a6F952#code

Can anyone help me to solve this puzzle?